# Trace matrix calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, trace, transpose

The square of the Frobenius norm of an $n\times d$ matrix $X$ is equal to Tr($X^TX$).

$$||X||_F^2 = \mathrm{Tr}(X^TX).$$

Then in the case of matrix involving addition or subtraction would be, for example,

$$||X-Y||_2^{2} = \mathrm{Tr}((X-Y)^T(X-Y)).$$

How do we solve in this case?
Can we just do as follows?

\begin{align}
||X-Y||_2^{2} &= \mathrm{Tr}((X-Y)^T(X-Y)) \\
&= \mathrm{Tr}((Y^T-X^T)(X-Y))\\
&=\mathrm{Tr}(Y^TX-Y^TY-X^TX+X^TY).
\end{align}

I'm not sure if this is mathematically correct.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "solve". In any case, your steps are incorrect. Note that $(A - B)^T = A^T - B^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace is linear, hence we have

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Tr}\big ((X - Y)^\intercal (X - Y)\big) &= \operatorname{Tr}\big ((X^\intercal - Y^\intercal)(X - Y)\big ) \\
&= \operatorname{Tr} (X^\intercal X - X^\intercal Y - Y^\intercal X + Y^\intercal Y )\\
&=\operatorname{Tr}(X^\intercal X) - \operatorname{Tr}(X^\intercal Y)- \operatorname{Tr}(Y^\intercal X) + \operatorname{Tr}(Y^\intercal Y).
\end{align}

In general, you can't simplify this result any further.

Comment: Gotcha. I was confused about the transpose part and this cleared my confusion. Thanks.